# Query in laravel returns empty response

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am tying to retrieve data from my data base using `leftJoin` in laravel. I have two table name `users` and `appointments` in my appointments table there is a field name `doctor_id` that holds the doctor id related to the id in users. both the id value is same. I need the name of doctors from `users` table and `appointment_date` , `status` from `appointments` table if the column id value in `users` table matches column appointments value in `appointments` table with a where clause where `patient_id = $patientID`. But when I execute my query it returns empty response.

*code*

```
$patientID = $request->patientID;
$prevAppointments = DB::table('appointments')
  ->leftJoin('users', 'appointments.doctor_id', '=', 'users.id')
  ->select(
    'users.first_name',
    'users.last_name',
    'appointments.appointment_date',
    'appointments.status'
  )
  ->where('appointments.patient_id', $patientID)
  ->get();
return($prevAppointments);
```

*user table*

[image: user table]

*appointments table*

[image: appointments table]

Comment: First, did you run query from your database. Do you've results there? Use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to share some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$patientID = $request->patientID;
$prevAppointments = DB::table('appointments')
                        ->leftJoin('users', 'appointments.doctor_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name','appointments.patient_id', 'appointments.appointment_date','appointments.status')
                        ->where('appointments.patient_id',$patientID)
                        ->get();
return($prevAppointments);
```

Comment: Still returns blank response

Comment: check your `$request->patientID;` and `doctor_id` have both for `users` and `appointments` table. I tested it already and it's working.

Comment: It worked. i am sorry my appointments table was blank.Thank you ;)

Comment: @Ajmal-Hossain Another important thing is you should practice one of the great feature of Laravel - Eloquent. It's give you better performance and less error and easy process what is already said "Hamid Shariati". Please have a look - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Answer (score 1):

create model with this command (if you don't have any Appointment Model):
inside root of your project type:

```
php artisan make:model Appointment
```

inside the created file write these:

```
protected $fillable=['patient_id','doctor_id','appointment_date','status'];

public function doctor(){
    $this->belongsTo(User::class,'doctor_id');
}
```

now you can use this Eloquent Query:
first add Appointment class:

```
 Use App\Appointment;
```

then use this in method:

```
 $prevAppointments = Appointment->where('patient_id','=',$patientID)->first();
```

now you have a collection that contain appointment with doctor properties. for more details on Eloquent ORM and Laravel Collections follow this link: https://hamidshariati.ir/most-important-articles-to-learn-laravel/

Comment: you did not get my question

Comment: if you use eloquent laws and if the table have data with that patient_id you got result. leftjoin and query that you use is more complicated and make more error.

Comment: you can test your query with type: php artisan tinker

Comment: also you can give constant to patient_id to sure if your query is right where you know patient_id has appointment and doctor_id is not null.